# Executing string as a evaluation in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php

class test
{
        private $linenum = "__LINE__ . \" - \" . __CLASS__";

        function exec()
        {
                return $$this->linenum;
        }
}

$x = new test();
print_r($x->exec());
```

I'm trying to declare a class variable with some contents that would be executed to a later time, I'm trying to achieve error_reporting and logging thru a function which doesn't need to use backtrace in order to find which file/line was executed previously.

eval() doesn't help as it would always report line 1 or 0 no matter what.

There is any possibility to achieve this in php without using debug_backgrace ? I'm working on a production env.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation of [PHP magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) explains:

> All these "magical" constants are resolved at compile time.

The compile time for strings passed to [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) happens when `eval()` is executed but `__LINE__` is inside the source code it gets for evaluation (i.e. the one line you generated in `$linenum`).

There is no way to implement logging using this idea.

Stick to [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). Even if it contains "debug" in it's name, it is always available in PHP (except if it is specifically disabled in `php.ini` under the [`disable_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) entry). All the most used frameworks and libraries use it when they need to produce nice logging.